# Unit test with Jest and Sinon in a Nuxt application

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, sinon

I'm adding a unit test to a Nuxt application and I'm using Jest and Sinon to stub functions.

I am trying to stub Axios get calls.

At the moment to create an instance doing this:

```js
return shallowMount(BarChart, {
  stubs: {
    highcharts: true
  },
  mocks: { $axios: axios }  
});
```

and my test I have this:

```js
test('Call getList', async () => {
  const wrapper = factory()
  const expected = []
  const data = { data: { items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] } }
  const stubFunc = sinon.stub(wrapper.vm.$axios, 'get').resolves(data)
  await wrapper.vm.getList()
  expect(wrapper.vm.chartOptions.series).toEqual(expected)
  stubFunc.restore()
})
```

My test passed but I got the following error in the console:

[image]

Any Idea on what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define axios stub when you do shallowMount.

For example:

```js
const data = { data: { items: [{ id: 1 }, { id: 2 }] } }
return shallowMount(BarChart, {
  stubs: {
    highcharts: true,
  },
  mocks: { 
    $axios: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(data)),
  },  
});
```

You do not need to use sinon, @vue/test-utils and jest have provided way to mock axios.